# Replace % in the end of string with Regex?

Tags: regex, abap

I want to remove `" %"` at the end of some text. I'd like to do it with a regular expression, because ABAP does not easily handle text at the end of a string.

```
DATA lv_vtext TYPE c LENGTH 10 VALUE 'TEST %'.
REPLACE REGEX ' %$' IN lv_vtext WITH ''.
```

But it does not replace anything. When I leave out `"$"` the text will be removed as expected, but I fear it might find more occurrences than wanted.

I experimented with `\z` or `\Z` instead of `$`, but to no avail.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I think your issue is due to an incorrect type assigned to `lv_vtext`. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
REPLACE REGEX '\s%\s*$' IN lv_vtext WITH ''
```

The benefit of using `\s` is that it matches any Unicode whitespace chars. The `\s*$` matches any trailing (white)spaces that you might have missed.

The whole pattern matches

- `\s` - any whitespace
- `%` - a `%` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - at the end of string.

Comment: As you suggested in your first comment, I also tried `\s%$`. But I had to insert the `\s*` to make it work. Bog knows what invisible whitespace is found here.

Comment: @Joesse I see, that is a common case when strings contain weird spaces at the end and since humans can't tell one from another, `\s` comes in very handy.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is about an alternative way without REGEX. POSIX regular expressions are quite slow, moreover some people are reluctant to use it, so if you're not completely closed to do it in normal ABAP:

```
lv_vtext = COND #( WHEN contains( val = lv_vtext end = ` %` ) 
           THEN substring( val = lv_vtext len = strlen( lv_vtext ) - 2 )
           ELSE lv_vtext ).
```

Code with context:

```
DATA(lv_vtext) = `test %`.
lv_vtext = COND #( WHEN contains( val = lv_vtext end = ` %` ) 
           THEN substring( val = lv_vtext len = strlen( lv_vtext ) - 2 )
           ELSE lv_vtext ).
ASSERT lv_vtext = `test`.
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. My ABAP knowledge is limited and I did not know the `COND` operator.